# Visual Studio 2012 C++ code coverage merge executables

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, code-coverage

My c++ unit tests use gtest framework so every test is a separate executable. I'm running the CodeCoverage.exe tool to get the raw coverage data of each executable run. When I open the results in Visual Studio, each executable run appears in a separate branch and the results can't be merged together.
Is there any way to make this work?

One thing I've tried is to specify `/session:uniq` in the command line for both runs but that didn't have any effect.

Comment: Interesting, looks like merging may have been supported in earlier versions of VS ([How to: Merge Code Coverage Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms318549(v=vs.100).aspx)), I wonder what it switched to.

Answer (score 2):

Does it help you to capture via vsperfcmd.exe?

1. Build your gtest with `/profile` flag specified to the linker
2. Instrument your gtest exe with Visual Studio coverage instrumentation

   - `vsinstr.exe gtest.exe /COVERAGE`
3. Launch the code coverage capture tool

   - `vsperfmon.exe /COVERAGE /OUTPUT:gtest.coverage`
4. Run the gtest
5. Stop the capture tool

   - `vsperfcmd.exe -shutdown`
6. Launch the output file (gtest.coverage) to see the output in Visual Studio

Comment: Does this still work in VS 2012? I thought it only did dynamic instrumentation.

Comment: Unfortunately at least in VS2015 this gives just the same result what shoosh mentiond in his question.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this should have been a comment, but I don't have the permissions yet.
You can run all your unit tests with the macro:
    RUN_ALL_TESTS();

Comment: That's not really an option for me. these unit tests must be separate executables.